# Always call method of current class

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

```
@interface A : NSObject

- (void) tmp;
- (void) foo;

@end

@implementation A

- (void) tmp {
    [self foo];
}

- (void) foo {
    NSLog(@"A");
}

@end
```

derived class

```
@interface B : A

- (void) foo;

@end

@implementation B

- (void) foo {
    NSLog(@"B");
}

@end
```

code

```
B * b = [[B alloc] init];
[b tmp]; // -> writes out B
```

is there a way to implement A, so a call to [self foo] inside [self tmp] in class A would result in calling A:foo not B:foo

**(so the output after calling [b foo] == @"B" and after calling [b tmp] == @"A")**

smth like

```
@implementation A

- (void) tmp {
    [ALWAYS_CALL_ON_A foo];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `super`

```
@implementation B

- (void) tmp {
     [super foo];
}
@end
```

Comment: cant this be done without super? simmilar to Parag Bafna but only without using class methods?

Comment: If you just omit the definition of `tmp` in `B` you get the same effect. @PeterLapisu what you're asking about is a non-virtual method. Objective-C doesn't have those (but C++ does).

Comment: Not realy, please notice that I call `[super foo]` not `[super tmp]`. If you omit this definition, you will get 'B' on the output.

Answer (score 0):

Use class methods

```
@interface A : NSObject {

}
- (void) tmp;
+ (void) foo;
@end

@implementation A
- (void) tmp {
    [A foo];
}

+ (void) foo {
    NSLog(@"A");
}
@end
#import "A.h"
@interface B : A {

}
+ (void) foo;
@end

@implementation B
+ (void) foo {
    NSLog(@"B");
}

@end
```

Comment: usecase - i cannot use a class method... can something like this be done with instance methods?